# Subset of array A in which if we do AND of all elements of that subset then output should be in power of two

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation

I got this solution to a problem where it states:

Given an array A. Is there any subset of array A in which if we do AND of all elements of that subset then output should be in power of two (for example : 1,2,4,8,16 and so on ).

Input: 
First line contains number of test cases T. Each test first line contains N size of array A and next line contains N space separated integers.

Output: 
For each test case print YES if there is any subset of array A in which if we do AND of all elements of that subset then output should be in power of two else print NO.

The solution is like this but I could not understand the below solution. Please help.

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            int[] arr = new int[num];
            String arrCnts = br.readLine();
            String[] arrStr = arrCnts.split(" ");
            boolean flag = false;
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for(int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                arr[j] = Integer.parseInt(arrStr[j]);
                if(max < arr[j]) {
                    max = arr[j];
                }
            }

            int len = (int) (java.lang.Math.log10(max) / java.lang.Math.log10(2));

            for (int k = 0; k <= len; k++) {
                int mask = 1 << k, mul = -1;//ffffffff
                for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                    if ((arr[j] & mask) != 0) {
                        if (mul == -1)
                            mul = arr[j];
                        else
                            mul &= arr[j];
                    }
                }
                if (mul == -1)
                    continue;
                else if (mul == mask) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(flag) {
                System.out.println("YES");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NO");
            }
        }


SAMPLE INPUT 
2
3
1 2 3
2
10 20

SAMPLE OUTPUT 
YES
NO
```

Comment: But you *did* understand the question? Because I don't... Example input and output would be helpful.

Comment: Could you please explain, what you wanted to say here: *Is there any subset of array A **in which if we do** AND of all elements of that subset then output should be in power of two (for example : 1,2,4,8,16 and so on ).*

Comment: Thanks, I have updated with sample input and output.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but here's a (likely) hint: What does a power of 2 look like when represented as a binary integer?  Are all binary integers that look this way powers of 2?  Next hint: Given some value x in the array, if ____ is true of x, then we know we can safely include x in *any* satisfying subset, otherwise we know it *can't* be in any such set.

Comment: @j_random_hacker : Thanks. For a power of 2, there should be only 1 and all other bits should be 0. Not all binary integers have this property. Also if a number x were to be power of 2, then x & (x-1) == 0. But I could not get your last hint regarding including or excluding x [subset] from entire set.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea for the algorithm is this :

> Let's note A_i the set of all the elements of A that have '1' in the ith position of their binary representation. If there is a subset S={s1,...,sn} of A such that AND(s1,...sn) = 2^i = 100...0 in binary (i zeroes), then the AND of all the elements of A_i is equal to 2^i, since S must be a subset of A_i.

What the algorithm does is compute the AND of the elements of A_i, for i from `0` to `len`, the number of bits used to write the biggest number of A minus 1. To do that, it uses a mask aptly named `mask`, equal to 2^i for `i` from `0` to `len`. Then, for each number in A, it checks if that number has a 1 in ith position by doing the test `(arr[j]&mask)!=0`. If that is the case, it updates `mul`, which originally is just all ones, with the AND of `arr[j]` with `mul`.

At the end of the inner loop, `mul` contains the AND of the elements of A_i. If for some `i`, `mask==mul`, then a subset that satisfies the property exists, otherwise no such subset exists.