# Need logic for this (ANDing list elements to get Power of Two)

Tags: python

I have a problem given as:

Given an array A. Is there any subset of array A in which if we do AND of all elements of that subset then output should be in power of two (for example : 1,2,4,8,16 and so on ).

After observation I tried it like this :

```
s = list(map(int,raw_input().split()))
x = [ True for x in s if x | (x+1) == (x+1)*2]
if len(x) > 0:
    print "YES"
else:
    print "NO"
```

Would somebody suggest any other logic than this?

Comment: how about some example i/o

Comment: Seems like a quiz problem. You can get the logic from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990794/subset-of-array-a-in-which-if-we-do-and-of-all-elements-of-that-subset-then-outp

Answer (score 2):

We'll use `itertools.combinations` to get all combinations of elements from the input set.

```
from itertools import combinations

def is_power_two(n):
    if n==1:
        return True
    if n<1:
        return False
    return is_power_two(n/2)

def do_they_and(s):
    for i in range(2, len(s)+1): 
        for j in combinations(s, i):
            total = 0
            for n in j:
                total &= n
            if is_power_two(total):
                return True
```

This is probably the simplest way to program it, but the best solution from an efficiency standpoint is probably a dynamic programming one.

Comment: this won't work for python 2.. use `from __future__ import division` to fix